# separate custom commands and document into different files

Tags: auxiliary-files, subfiles, multiple-files

I have some extensive calls of `\renewcommand{}` that are cluttering my `document.tex` file. I would like to save them in a separate file (`costum_definitions`).

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{color}

% begin definitions
\definecolor{myOrange}{rgb}{0.7,0.4,0}
\setlength{\parskip}{.25cm}
% end definitions

\begin{document}
    \lipsum
\end{document}
```

I would like to include everything between `% begin definitions` and `% end definitions` in a separate file and call on that file in one line to make the commands available in my document.

Comment: And what is the problem? Simply do it and then use \input (or \usepackage if you called the file custom_definitions.sty).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\input{costum_definitions} % include custom definitions from separate file
```